# python3.5 --version command not found CentOS 7

Tags: python, linux, centos, centos7

After installation of python 3.5.2 on CentOS 7 command "python3.5 -V" cannot find this command. There is python2.7 installed by default and if we type "python -V" we can see the version 2.7.5. How can I install python 3.5.2 on CentOS to make "python3.5 -V"(and other commands with python3.5) work.

Comment: how did you install python 3.5? does `python3 -V` work?

Comment: The problem was solved. It was about root privileges. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See all the versions of Python you have available:

```
$ compgen -c | grep "^python"
```

The output will be something like

```
python3
python3-32
python3-config
python3.5
python3.5-32
python3.5-config
python3.5m
python3.5m-config
python3
python3-32
python3-config
python3.5
python3.5-32
python3.5-config
python3.5m
python3.5m-config
python
python-config
python2.6
python2.6-config
python2.7
python2.7-config
pythonw
pythonw2.6
pythonw2.7
```

Make sure the version you're looking for is in that list. Then, take that and run (if `python3.5` is in the list):

```
$ python3.5 -V
```

Which should output something like

```
Python 3.5.2
```